# How do i call a function in a doGet function?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like to run the function afterFormSubmit(e) once function doGet(request) is initiated.

I tried calling the function afterFormSubmit within doGet(request), but it wont run.

Is this possible to actually run afterFormSubmit within the doGet function?

Below is a sample of the code.

Thanks.

```js
var DONE = "DONE";
var Approve = "Approve";
var Reject = "Reject";
var EMAIL_SENT = "EMAIL_SENT";
var FOR_RUN = "FOR_RUN";
var COMPLETE = "COMPLETE";

function afterFormSubmit(e) {
  const entryRow = e.range.getRow();
  const ss =
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Form Responses 1");

  var su = ss.getRange(entryRow, 14).getValue();
  var ku = ss.getRange(entryRow, 14).getValue();
  var check = ss.getRange(entryRow, 9).getValue();
  var checke = ss.getRange(entryRow, 16).getValue();
  var checkv = ss.getRange(entryRow, 17).getValue();

  if (check == "" && checke != EMAIL_SENT) {
    assignEditUrls();
    sendMail_Verification(e);
  }

  if (check == Approve && checkv != EMAIL_SENT) {
    const info = e.namedValues;
    const pdfFile = createPDF(info, e);

    ss.getRange(entryRow, 14).setValue(pdfFile.getUrl());
    ss.getRange(entryRow, 15).setValue(pdfFile.getName());

    Last_sendMail(e);
  }
  sendMail_Rejection(e);
}

function doGet(request) {
  Logger.log(request);

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(request.parameters.ssId).getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  var user = request.parameters.id;
  var status = request.parameters.status;
  var check = request.parameters.check;

  for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
    var check = sheet.getRange(i + 1, 12, 1, 1).getValue();
    if (data[i][0] == user[0] && check != DONE) {
      sheet.getRange(i + 1, 9, 1, 1).setValue(status[0]);

      var checkcc = sheet.getRange(i + 1, 9, 1, 1).getValue();
      if (data[i][0] == user[0] && check != DONE) {
        var date = Utilities.formatDate(
          new Date(),
          "GMT+08:00",
          "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"
        );
        sheet.getRange(i + 1, 19, 1, 1).setValue("");
        sheet.getRange(i + 1, 13, 1, 1).setValue(date);
        sheet.getRange(i + 1, 12, 1, 1).setValue(DONE);

        if (checkcc == Approve) {
          var result = "You have successfully Approved " + user + " request.";
          return ContentService.createTextOutput(result);
        } else if (checkcc == Reject) {
          var resultvc = "You have successfully Rejected " + user + " request.";
          return ContentService.createTextOutput(resultvc);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Outline of general process being followed:

- A google form is submitted with respondents data
- An email goes out to the verifier with the data submitted using e.range
- In the email to the verifier, to approve or reject a request. This is where the doGet comes in.
- I would like to trigger an email out to the respondent once the verifier approves.

Comment: how did you try calling the function?

Comment: function doGet(request){afterFormSubmit(request);} within the doGet function.

Comment: what was the error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand your process is the following:

1. A user fills a form and this has an `onSubmit` trigger.
2. This form information is used to populate a spreadsheet and to send an email to a verifier.
3. You want the verifier to be able to click a button to approve or reject.
4. Finally an email should be sent to the user informing of the decision.

What you seem to want to do, is to make the `afterFormSubmit` function serve two purposes.

- Receive the form
- Receive the approval or rejection from the `doGet` triggered from the email.

Now, while this is possible, I don't think its necessary, it just seems to make things more complicated.

I would suggest that the functions do the following:

1. `afterFormSubmit` - receive the form info, populate spreadsheet and send email to verifier.
2. `doGet` - receive the approval, populate spreadsheet and send approval email to end user.

Comment: Thanks @iansedano.

used this : var data = ss.getRange(2,1,i,18).getDisplayValues();

Answer (score 0):

`afterFormSubmit(request)` sounds like an onFormSubmit triggered function which is generally called by a trigger and the trigger fills the first parameter with an event object.  So you can call it as long as you supply the event object.  To learn more about the event object put Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e)) in the first line after the function declaration where e is the parameter that is holding the event object.  Then do a form submission and you can go to executions to see the structure and contents of the event object which you must supply if you wish to call it directly yourself.

Do something like this in your onFormSubmit

function onMyFormSubmit(e) {
PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperties()['requesters name'] = e.range.rowStart;
}

Then you can get it out of PropertiesService from the doGet and get immediate access to the row in the linked sheet.

Comment: Thanks @Cooper.
I am trying to use const entryRow = e.range.getRow(); in afterFormSubmit(). 
So that i am able to get the values on the current row once doGet is initialized. But it says getRow not recognised.

I tried getLastRow() but that doesnt seem to give me the value on the row that doGet is inputting values into.

Comment: Why not just use e.values or e.namedValues they already have the value and you don't have to perform another function to get them.

Comment: The reason i cant, is that first i have a submission from a google form with data already in sheet.
secondly an email goes out upon form submit for verification.
thirdly once approve link is clicked, doGet initializes.
Lastly i would like to get the exact row where doGet initialized from.

Comment: e.range.getRow(). I want to be able to do this with the already logged data on sheet once doGet runs. So it should be able to run from the exact row.

Comment: What's the big picture here? What are you trying to accomplish? Zoom out a little bit and gives a better understanding of what you trying to accomplish.

Comment: Alright.

A google form is submitted with respondents data
An email goes out to the verifier with the data submitted using e.range
In the email to the verifier, to approve or reject a request.This is where the doGet comes in.

So i would like to trigger an email out to the respondent upon approval once the verifier approves.

The problem is, i cant use e.value cos it is not a form submission where i can use OnFormSubmit trigger.

So i pass the function sendEmail into doGet. but the email sent selects the lastRow instead of current row i am working on.

Thats pretty much it.

Comment: What is the web app for?

Comment: Its for the approval/reject link. which then logs what time the verifier approved the request unto the spreadsheet.

Comment: So at that point you need something in the web app that allows you to go directly into the linked sheet and get the additional information to send an email to the requester and that information should have been e.range.rowStart.

Comment: So at that point you need something in the web app that allows you to go directly into the linked sheet and get the additional information to send an email to the requester and that information should have been e.range.rowStart.    All you need is the row number which was available to you in the first form submit as e.range.rowStart in the event object. So you need to put that data some where in an object whose properties are perhaps the requesters names.  You can store the object in PropertiesService.

Comment: thanks. 
You mean something like this: 

var lastRowNo = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty("lastRowNo");
  if( lastRowNo != null ){
    jumpRow( parseInt(lastRowNo) );
  }
}

Comment: Yeah, except that it probably wont be the last row all of the time.  It will be whatever e.range.rowStart is in the event object of the onFormSubmit function which is where you should set it up.

Comment: Thanks again.
for on Formsbumit{ PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperties()['requesters name'] = e.range.rowStart; }

Pls can you show me how to use it in doGet? based on my code?

Thank you.

Comment: You don't want to run the form submit function in doGet().  Instead you should write another function that accesses the linked sheet and uses the row that's in the PropertiesService under that name of the requester that is getting replied to.  The row should have been put there during the onFormSubmit when he first submitted his/her request.

Comment: Thanks @Cooper. I cant seem to get it to work. May have to try some other method. Very much appreciated.

Comment: What values are submitted by the requestor that can be used for the key in the PropertiesService object that your code will know when the request is approved/rejected.   Also what does the person do to approve or reject a request and what information is provide?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236069/discussion-between-king-michael-king-and-cooper).